# Could Not Find Image File in React Native

Tags: image, react-native

I have defined a React Native class that is designed to fill a "tableView" cell with an image reference that is a prop input to the class. This is invoked with the use of FlatList. However, this class is unable to find the input image reference in the bundle when specified using an Image source tag. It can only be found if it is a hard coded reference.

The class is defined as follows:

```
class ListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    _onPress = () => {
        this.props.onPressItem(this.props.index);
    }

    render() {
        const item = this.props.item; 

        console.log("ChannelSelection Mix Button artwork: ", item.artwork);
        return (
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={this._onPress}
            underlayColor="transparent">
            <View>
              <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                <Image source={{ uri: item.artwork }} style={styles.buttonContainer} />
                <View style={styles.mixButtonTitleContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.mixButtonTitle}
                    numberOfLines={2}>{item.channelTitle}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
}
```

When this class in invoked, I get a warning that says:

```
Warning
Could not find image file:///Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34AE8A68-E69D-4804-B3C4-96DE7A051B9B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C79368E9-3D1B-492C-B72B-9BF5C4D3262B/myApp.app/./Resources/MissingAlbumArt.png
```

The console output to print item.artwork is:

```
'ChannelSelection Mix Button artwork: ', './Resources/MissingAlbumArt.png'
```

so you can see that the name of the file is being passed in correctly.

Note that if I change the line:

```
<Image source={{ uri: item.artwork }} style={styles.buttonContainer} />
```

to:

```
<Image source={require('./Resources/MissingAlbumArt.png')} style={styles.buttonContainer} />
```

then the error goes away.

So, how can I properly reference the .png files in my Resources directory? And why are my .png files not in the Resources directory of my bundle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Using images with `require`

One way of using images is in the bundle. You access these images by using

```
const imageName = require('./path/to/the/image/imageName.png');
```

For images that I add this way I actually create a file (called `Images.js`) that contains all of my requires and then exports the images. So in the file it would be a list of requires like this

```
export const imageName = require('./path/to/the/image/imageName.png');
```

Then when I want to use the image I import the image like so:

```
import { imageName } from '.path/to/Images.js';
```

## Using images on the device

Another way is to download the file and then save it in the documents directory of the application. Usually you use `rn-fetch-blob` or `react-native-fs` to download and save the file to a location, like the documents directory.

You would then construct the the path to the file and use that. So for example, if you were using `react-native-fs` you could construct the path in the following way,

```
let pathToImage = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/path/to/dowloaded/file/imageName.png'
```

## What's happening in your situation

You are mixing the two methods up. The images haven't been stored on your device when you are working in development. They are currently served to the device by the bundler. That way you have to use the `require` method to access them. They get copied across when you use them (look at the logs in your bundler and you will see it happening).

When you create your production `ipa` or `apk` all the images and code get bundled together and added to the app, the `require` statements tell the device where to find the images in that bundle. If you were to try to use the path of the file after it has been bundled into an `ipa` or `apk` it wouldn't work in development and you would end up with a similar error.

If you try to access the file using a path similar to the one below, it won't work as that file isn't there because the file is in the bundle. It is best to use the `require` method.

```
file:///Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34AE8A68-E69D-4804-B3C4-96DE7A051B9B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C79368E9-3D1B-492C-B72B-9BF5C4D3262B/myApp.app/./Resources/MissingAlbumArt.png
```

One thing to also note is that `iOS` cannot guarantee that paths to files will remain static. If you run `react-native run-ios` although the application is reloaded and only one application appears on device, it can actually move folders so it is always best to dynamically construct links to files that you have saved to any directory on `iOS`.

## Snack

Here is a snack that shows using `Images.js` to store all the require for the files. https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/requiring-images

Here is the directory structure that I have in this project

```
├── App.js
├── Images.js
├── README.md
├── app.json
├── assets
│   ├── bart.png
│   ├── lisa.png
│   ├── maggie.png
│   └── parents
│       ├── homer.jpg
│       └── marge.jpg
├── components
│   ├── AssetExample.js
│   └── SecondAssetExample.js
└── package.json
```

Here is how I am constructing the `require` statements in the `Images.js`

```
export const MARGE = require('./assets/parents/marge.jpg');
export const HOMER = require('./assets/parents/homer.jpg');
export const BART = require('./assets/bart.png');
export const MAGGIE = require('./assets/maggie.png');
export const LISA = require('./assets/lisa.png');
```

Comment: I tried your idea of creating a Images.js file with exports for each .png file, but am getting an error. The lines of the file look like this: export const MissingAlbumArt = require('./Resources/MissingAlbumArt.png'); The error I am getting is "Requiring unknown module '694'. If you are sure the file is there, try restarting metro bundler. ..." Did I implement this as you suggested?

Comment: Your file paths really depend on where you store the files, you should make sure that they are correct. Usually when adding new files to a project I like to make sure that my metro bundler is  clear. That error is usually because you have added/removed something and it is looking for it. Clear your [cache](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d), clean your build folders and try re-building the project

Comment: Sorry, I hate to be so dense on this, but I'm not getting it. If I move my .png files into the same directory as my source files and modify the content of the Images.js file to have lines such as "export const MissingAlbumArt = require('./MissingAlbumArt.png');", then the error about the metro bundler goes away. So does that mean that I can't have a separate directory called "Resources" that contains all my .png files? I suspect not, but why isn't it working?

Comment: And in addition, the import statement of "import MissingAlbumArt from './Images.js';" is not setting MissingAlbumArt with the expected value of './MissingAlbumArt.png'. It is left undefined. If you could indulge me for a few more minutes to answer these follow up questions, I would be most grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You can have a separate directory you just have to put the correct path in the require. I don't know how you have setup your project and where you have put your files.  The path in the `require` is relative to where the `Image.js` file is. Your import statement should be `import { MissingAlbumArt } from './Images.js'` note the `{}` around the `MissingAlbumArt`

Comment: Ok, the {} fixed the undefined problem. The only problems is that the value that is assigned to MissingAlbumArt is the index value in the Images.js file. For example, using the statement "import { MissingAlbumArt } from './Images.js';" (where the 3rd line of Images.js is "export const MissingAlbumArt = require('./MissingAlbumArt.png');") , and the statement "console.log("Missing artwork: ", MissingAlbumArt);" is executed from inside my render() method, the output printed in the console window is "'ChannelSelection Missing artwork: ', 3". Shouldn't the output be ./MissingAlbumArt.png'?

Comment: No, that seems correct. It gives a reference that it can use to find the image. I have added a snack so you can see a sample folder structure with it working. The folder structure is incidental as it can be anything, you just have to use the correct paths to the images you require and the correct path when you are importing `Images.js`

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I can't figure out how to pass that reference to a ListItem function through a FlatList as part of the data, such that the ListItem function can render the image. If I pass {MissingAlbumArt} in the data (e.g. data.artwork = {MissingAlbumArt}), the function receives {MissingAlbumArt, 3}. But if I then use <Image source=item.artwork ...\>, the image does not display in the view. The ListItem function is able to display text data from the input item, just not this image reference. Thoughts?

Comment: I showed an example in the [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/requiring-images) of passing an object containing the reference to an image. Look at what I am passing to the `SecondAssetExample`. As a bonus here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/Sk7gm7784) that incorporates a FlatList.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your example. In my previous comment, I should have had "data.artwork = MissingAlbumArt" instead of "data.artwork = {MissingAlbumArt}". You went beyond the call of duty. Thanks so much.